# How to create flexible audio player with background services and mini player in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, avaudioplayer

i want to create a flutter app in which music player is created
1)first screen will be list of audio ,which is from network url (with just audio package)
2)after click on one audio it will redirect to next screen on that screen audio player is playing(with audio image,artis name,and shor description)
3)after that audio is continue  playing and user redirect to previous screen the mini audio player will open for all app screens
3)when app is close audio will continue playing (i created already with background audio)

Comment: So what is the question? You've told us what you want to do. But you've not told us the difficulty you are facing. What is the question?

Comment: i created a flutter app in which i used just audio package for audio player and also used background audio for background music,but now i want to create a  one common mini player for all pages of app

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIqB8qEZW1U ,i refered this video for audio player